# Prevent cygwin bash from logging error on shebang

Tags: bash, cygwin, shebang

When running bash scripts in cygwin from the Windows command prompt, I always get a error on line 1, even when the script runs correctly

```
C:\ImageMagickWatchFolder>bash .\whitebalance
.\whitebalance: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
... (rest of script output)
```

(`whitebalance` is the filename of the script)

I've tried replacing line 1 of the script with

- `#!/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bash`
- `#!bash`
- `#!C:\cygwin64\bin\bash`
- `#!C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash`

among others, and just eliminating it entirely, all to no avail.  (Some give `No such file or directory` and some give `command not found`).  In particular, with first line empty, it gives

```
C:\ImageMagickWatchFolder>bash .\whitebalance
.\whitebalance: line 1: $'\357\273\277': command not found
```

I also tried switching line ending styles from unix to windows but that just made things worse.

To the first comment below:

```
C:\ImageMagickWatchFolder>head -n 2 whitebalance | cat -A
M-oM-;M-?#!/bin/bash$
coords=""$
```

Comment: Can you show the output of running `head -n 2 whitebalance | cat -A`? The shebang line should be entirely ignored if you are running the script through the shell manually though.

Comment: @EtanReisner Since formatting is lost in comments, I updated the question with the requested output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had been saving the script in Notepad++ in UTF-8-BOM encoding.  When changed to UTF-8 or ANSI, the error no longer occurred.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell from here, but one common way this happens is because of line endings. Make sure your script does not have `\r\n` (Windows-style) line endings. `bash` will ignore these but the shebang will still not work: it will try to find `/bin/bash\r`, and fail.

Comment: Why is the shebang being used at all when running the script manually though? That's the bit I can't figure out.

Comment: Yeah I checked that too and forgot to mention in the question.  Will update it.